# Error while importing Librosa on python

Tags: python, import, compiler-errors, librosa

I am struggling to import Librosa library for sound analyses. When I enter

```
import librosa
```

I get the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import decompose
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\librosa\decompose.py", line 19, in <module>
    import sklearn.decomposition
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 406, in <module>
    if np_version < (1, 12, 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

I am trying to do everything on Windows OS, Python 3.5 64-bit. Do I need to install some other libraries? I already installed a bunch of other libraries like numpy, matplotlib, scipy and few other essential ones. Please explain what's going on :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using: pip install librosa

```
You should get a bunch of messages like:

Collecting librosa
  Downloading librosa-0.5.1.tar.gz (1.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 312kB/s
Collecting audioread>=2.0.0 (from librosa)
  Downloading audioread-2.1.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.0 in c:\users\j\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from librosa)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.0 in c:\users\j\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from librosa)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.14.0 in c:\users\j\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from librosa)
Collecting joblib>=0.7.0 (from librosa)
  Downloading joblib-0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (176kB)

etc. etc. etc.
```

And then librosa among other libs is installed.

PS. looks like we are working on the same project??