# Error while importing Librosa on python (from jupyter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

I'm trynig to import librosa model via Jupyter notebook, but I'm getting error:

```
import librosa

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 66, in <module>
    from paramiko.sftp_client import SFTPClient

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 41, in <module>
    from paramiko.sftp_file import SFTPFile

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py", line 66
    self._close(async=True)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using `python 3.8` and `librosa==0.8.1`

I saw [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911383/error-while-importing-librosa-on-python) with no answer, so I'm tying again if there is new solution?

Comment: That does not seem like a complete backtrace?

Comment: That exception does not seem to have anything to do with librosa - but something related to your "paramiko" install

Comment: I run `import librosa` on `Linux Mint 20.3`, `Python 3.8`, `librosa 0.8.1` and can't reproduce this problem

Comment: did you test it directly in Python - without `Jupyter Notebook`? Maybe this is problem with `Jupyter Notebook`